# how to match the datetime format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have to match the datetime format in my controller and reject the request if it does not match the format. I have been thinking to do something like this

```
def datetime_range(from, to)
  raise ArgumentError if format_check
  (DateTime.parse(from))..(DateTime.parse(to))
end
```

But i'm not sure how to match the format of datetime without using regex.

Comment: Why don't you want to use regex?

Comment: What is the format you expect? What values can break it?

Comment: if the params contain empty, nil or invalid dates. Then it breaks actually.

Comment: empty and nil can be avoided using `present?` method but in order to check the validity, i wanted to match the format.

Comment: Do you want to allow any valid date format OR a specific one? Because in `DateTime.parse('2018-08-20')` and `DateTime.parse('20-08-2018')`, the formats are different but they return the same date(time).

Comment: For any valid date format, you can parse them separately and rescue `ArgumentError` which occurs for invalid date formats and then check if `from` OR `to` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strptime](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class) on the `DateTime` class

```
DateTime.strptime(params[:datetime], allowed_format) 
# raises ArgumentError: invalid date if the string violates the format
```

Example usage in a controller

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :parse_date

  def create
    # Do something with @date
  end

  private 

   def parse_date
     @date = DateTime.strptime(params[:date], '%Y-%m-%d')
   end
end
```

Comment: I followed your approach of before_filter and i'm using DateTime.parse

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you want to use `Time.zone.parse` to handle timezones correctly.

I would handle this task with a virtual model.

```
# custom validator for dates
class DateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value.try(:acts_like_time?) || value.try(:acts_like_date?)
      record.errors.add attribute, 'is not a valid date'
    end
  end
end

# call this whatever you want
class Query
  include ActiveModel::Model
  attr_accessor :from_date, :to_date

  validates :from_date, presence: true, date: true
  validates :to_date, presence: true, date: true

  def from_date=(value)
    @from_date = convert_to_time(value)
  end

  def to_date=(value)
    @to_date = convert_to_time(value)
  end

  def date_range
    @from_date..@to_date
  end

  private
    def convert_to_time(value)
      return value if value.try(:acts_like_time?)
      if value.try(:acts_like_string?)
        begin
          Time.zone.parse(value)
        rescue ArgumentError
          nil
        end
      end
    end
end
```

But you don't really need to reinvent the wheel of handling date attributes and validating them as there are plenty of gems that handle that like [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness).

This might seem like overkill but you handle it just like any resource in the controller:

```
# this is just a simplefied example of filtering a resource
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @foos = Foo.all 
    if query_attributes.any?
      @query = Query.new(query_attributes)
      if @query.valid?
        @foos = Foo.where(created_at: @query.date_range)
      else
        # do something else
      end
    end 
  end

  private
    def query_attributes
      params.fetch(:query)
            .permit(:from_date, :to_date)
    end
end
```

And use it with forms and the HTML5 date helper:

```
<%= form_for @query || Query.new do |f| %>

  <% if @query.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @query.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
    <li><% m %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :from_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :from_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <%= f.label :to_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :to_date %>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

It also keeps the logic in a seperate domain object which is easy to test instead of bloating the controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [`DateTime#iso8601`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-iso8601) method.

```
DateTime.iso8601('2018-08-10')
#=> Fri, 10 Aug 2018 00:00:00 +0000

DateTime.iso8601('2018-08-10T18:37')
#=> Fri, 10 Aug 2018 18:37:00 +0000

DateTime.iso8601('2018-08-10T18:37+02')
#=> Fri, 10 Aug 2018 18:37:00 +0200

DateTime.iso8601('2018-08-1018:37+02') # forgot T
#=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

This method raises an `ArgumentError` if the date is invalid, you can rescue from that and provide an error.

When using this method keep in mind that some results might not be what you expect:

```
DateTime.iso8601('2017')
#=> => Fri, 10 Aug 2018 20:17:00 +0000
# Sets only the time to (20:17) but keeps the current day

DateTime.iso8601('2017-11')
#=> Wed, 11 Jan 2017 00:00:00 +0000
# Set the year and the amount of days from start of year
```